# Disable gallery in 3.5 media iframe

Tags: uploads, gallery

I'm creating a setting to set a logo. It works but there is a problem.
I only need one image to be set so the gallery item should be disabled / hidden. Of course this should only effect this page, of even better this setting.

```
<?php
// above this I do a simple settings api
?>
<input id="set_logo" type="text" size="100" name="set_logo" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?>" />
<?php
do_action( 'media_buttons', 'set_logo' );
```

I've looked in multiple places in code but I can't find any clues how to do this.

**EDIT**
I've solved it in a different way that is not related to this. The solution is now implemented in my first plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/default-featured-image/
*shameless plug.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable tabs using a filter hook. Replace wpse_76095_isOurMediaUpload() with however you determine that you're running the media popup.

```
add_filter('media_upload_tabs', 'wpse_76095_filterMediaUploadTabs');

/**
* filter out unwanted media upload tabs
* @param array $tabs
* @return array
*/
function wpse_76095_filterMediaUploadTabs($tabs) {
    if (wpse_76095_isOurMediaUpload()) {
        unset(
            $tabs['type_url'],  // no linking from external sites (no local image)
            $tabs['gallery'],   // no galleries
            $tabs['nextgen']    // no NextGEN galleries
        );
    }

    return $tabs;
}
```

Comment: This only works for WP pre-3.5. Check the answer by Brasofilo.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't reproduced the particulars of the Q. But the following works to disable the <kbd>Create Gallery</kbd> link from the new media interface:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'disable_media_gallery_wpse_76095' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', 'disable_media_gallery_wpse_76095' );
function disable_media_gallery_wpse_76095() 
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
        $(document.body).one( 'click', '.insert-media', function( event ) {
            $(".media-menu").find("a:contains('Gallery')").remove();
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

*ps: I just discovered the [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) in jQuery, nice one ;)*

[image: remove gallery from new media uploader]

Comment: Ahh thanes for the response. But I already found a solution, and implemented it in my plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/default-featured-image/

Comment: Well, the Question was hanging all alone in Unanswered list... Would be nice then that you added an Answer with your solution.

Comment: Yes I understand but the way I solved it is so different (in code) It doesn't fit. And I kinda forgot this question :|

Comment: The 'unset( $strings['createGalleryTitle'] );' solution does not work properly on WP 3.6- but this did. Cheers.